# Качество скриншотов в Play Market

Tags: java, android, google-play

Залил свое приложение в Google Play. Пытаюсь добавить скриншоты. Изначально они выглядят хорошо, но после заливки, видимо, очень сильно сжимаются, из-за чего сильно теряют качество. Что с этим можно сделать?

До заливки/в самом play market[image: до]

[image: после]

Comment: Скриншоты в каком формате отправляете?

Comment: пробовал .jpg и .png

Answer (score 0):

Увы, вашу проблему никак не решить... Плеймаркет так или иначе будет ужимать картинки,даже если вы загрузите их самого высокого расширения. И все же, воспользуйтесь телефоном с 6'' экраном и расширением FullHd. Это повысит четкость.

Отдельно замечу: если у Вас не предусмотрена адаптивная верстка для маленьких экранов, то здесь проблемы не только со скриншотами. Вы нарушили ряд правил дизайна, потому как элементы получились маленькими. Если открыть такой приложение на 5'' стареньком экране, то все пометки ужмутся до 1-1,5 слов, их  придется постоянно открывать, чтобы прочитать - не удобно... Но Москва тоже не сразу строилась =)